# Install imutils using conda in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, anaconda, conda, ubuntu-16.04

Hi, I am working in computer vision projects, I installed python 3.5 using anaconda in my laptop (Ubunut16.04 LTS). Can you please tell me, How I install imutils using conda in my ubuntu 16.04 LTS.??????

Comment: what are you using imutils for? if for resizing, just use cv2.resize

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
pip install imutils
```

This should install imutils and its requirements (numpy, astropy, scipy).

The documentation is [here](http://imutils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/imutils/install.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

conda install -c mlgill imutils

Answer (score 1):

I was getting error while installing in anaconda env (pip install imutils ,and conda install -c mlgill imutils) both are not working.

so alternative solution.

Download [imutils](https://github.com/jrosebr1/imutils) and then extract file

```
import sys

import os

#PATH location of downloaded file example 
#PATH='/home/golu/Documents/ocr/imutils-master/'
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(PATH))

#Now it works
import imutils
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you have a pip linkd to another python you might want to make sure you install imutils using the Anaconda pip:

```
Wed Nov 01 21:57:17 :~/CS585/hw4/basic-motion-detection$ which -a pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
/Users/mona/anaconda/bin/pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
/Users/mona/anaconda/bin/pip
Wed Nov 01 21:58:03 :~/CS585/hw4/basic-motion-detection$ sudo /Users/mona/anaconda/bin/pip install imutils
Password:
The directory '/Users/mona/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/mona/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting imutils
  Downloading imutils-0.4.3.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: imutils
  Running setup.py install for imutils ... done
Successfully installed imutils-0.4.3
```